# Double buffered ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, doublebuffered

I have a CheckedListBox (WinForms) control (which inherits from ListBox; googling shows that the problem is with ListBox) that is anchored to all four sides of its form.  When the form is resized, the ListBox has an ugly flicker.  I tried inheriting CheckedListBox and setting `DoubleBuffered` to `true` in the ctor (this technique works with other controls, including ListView and DataGridView), but it had no effect.

I tried adding the [`WS_EX_COMPOSITED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680.aspx) style to `CreateParams`, and this helped, but makes the form resize mush more slowly.

Is there any other way to prevent this flickering?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having similar issues albeit with an owner drawn listbox.  My solution was to use BufferedGraphics objects.  Your mileage may vary with this solution if your list isn't owner drawn, but maybe it will give you some inspiration.

I found that TextRenderer had difficulties rendering to the correct location unless I suppled TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsTranslateTransform.  The alternative to this was to use P/Invoke to call BitBlt to directly copy pixels between the graphics contexts.  I chose this as the lesser of two evils.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is a double-buffered ListBox for owner drawing.
/// The double-buffering is accomplished by creating a custom,
/// off-screen buffer during painting.
/// </summary>
public sealed class DoubleBufferedListBox : ListBox
{
    #region Method Overrides
    /// <summary>
    /// Override OnTemplateListDrawItem to supply an off-screen buffer to event
    /// handlers.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        BufferedGraphicsContext currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;

        Rectangle newBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
        using (BufferedGraphics bufferedGraphics = currentContext.Allocate(e.Graphics, newBounds))
        {
            DrawItemEventArgs newArgs = new DrawItemEventArgs(
                bufferedGraphics.Graphics, e.Font, newBounds, e.Index, e.State, e.ForeColor, e.BackColor);

            // Supply the real OnTemplateListDrawItem with the off-screen graphics context
            base.OnDrawItem(newArgs);

            // Wrapper around BitBlt
            GDI.CopyGraphics(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, bufferedGraphics.Graphics, new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

---

The `GDI` class (suggested by **frenchtoast**).

```
public static class GDI
{
    private const UInt32 SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020;

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, UInt32 dwRop);

    public static void CopyGraphics(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, Graphics bufferedGraphics, Point p)
    {
        IntPtr hdc1 = g.GetHdc();
        IntPtr hdc2 = bufferedGraphics.GetHdc();

        BitBlt(hdc1, bounds.X, bounds.Y, 
            bounds.Width, bounds.Height, hdc2, p.X, p.Y, SRCCOPY);

        g.ReleaseHdc(hdc1);
        bufferedGraphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eric: Where do you get GDI from? Is it a reference? For example, I've tried to add `Graphics GDI = this.CreateGraphics();` but it doesn't have the CopyGraphics method. Or did you import Gdi32.dll previously?

Comment: Ok - working now. I've added `GDI32.dll` with `BitBlt` method, wrapped it as `GDI.CopyGraphics(...)` and now it works ... the only thing is that is flickering just the same as the original ListBox. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @Matt: Is the ListBox set to be OwnerDrawn?

Comment: @Eric - are you referring to this MSDN article: [How to create an OwnerDrawn Listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229679(v=vs.90).aspx)? This creates a listbox derived from the `Control` class rather than from the `ListBox` class, which needs more code.

Comment: @Matt: You need to set the DrawStyle property on the ListBox to OwnerDrawn.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the hint, `OnDrawItem` is called after I've changed the DrawMode. I can see now that I have some issue with the BitBlt, since the ListBox window is entirely empty - will have to sort this out.

Comment: @Matt: The window is empty because with an OwnerDrawn ListBox, you have to draw the content (text and/or graphics) for each item in the ListBox by handling the DrawItem event.

Comment: @Eric: I've added         `private void listBoxOutput_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var lb = (ListBox)sender;
            var item = lb.Items[e.Index].ToString();
            var brush = Brushes.Black;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item, lb.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
        }`
which works in a normal ListBox with `DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed`, with the DoubleBufferedListbox, only the vertical scrollbar is updated, the textarea remains blank. A breakpoint shows that the code is executed.

Comment: Eric, could you please post the `GDI.CopyGraphics` wrapper method?

Comment: @JeremyThompson: It's not complex but requires quite a bit of code.  At its core, it is a wrapper around the BitBlt GDI method, which uses several structs and enums.  You can check pinvoke.net for some details on how to wrap that.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, I googled GDI.CopyGraphics, and found it [here](https://github.com/idunnololz/DivisionByZeroLevelEditor/blob/master/GeneralControlLibrary/GDI.cs)

Answer (score 3):

You could check if switching to a ListView Control with checkboxes improves matters. It's not as easy to deal with (but hey, the WinForms ListBox isn't a stroke of genius either), I found that it's resize behavior with `DoubleBuffered=true` is bearable.

Alternatively, you could try to reduce flicker by overriding the parent forms background drawing - either providing a hollow brush, or overriding `WM_ERASEBKND` by doing nothing and returning `TRUE`. (that's ok if your control covers the entire client area of the parent form, otherwise you'd need a more complex background drawing method.

I've used this successfully in Win32 applications, but I don't know if the Forms control adds some of it's own magic that renders this nonfunctional.

Comment: It's a private property, but it can be set using reflection:
`typeof(ListBox).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(myListBox, true);`

Answer (score 0):

This used to be handled by sending the WM_SETREDRAW message to the control.

```
const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0x0b;

Message m = Message.Create(yourlistbox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr) 0, (IntPtr) 0);
yourform.DefWndProc(ref m);

// do your updating or whatever else causes the flicker

Message m = Message.Create(yourlistbox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr) 1, (IntPtr) 0);
yourform.DefWndProc(ref m);
```

See also: [WM_SETREDRAW reference at Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219%28VS.85%29.aspx)  *Fixed Link*

If anyone else has used windows messages under .NET, please update this posting as necessary.

Comment: The flicker is caused by resize, so this isn't an optimal solution.  However, I might do it anyway.

Comment: This does not solve the flickering problem on my ListBox.

Comment: This answer is wrong because your code is not even executed when the Form is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Although not addressing the specific issue of flickering, a method that is frequently effective for this type of issue is to cache a minimal state of the ListBox items. Then determine whether you need to redraw the ListBox by performing some calculation on each item. Only update the ListBox if at least one item needs to be updated (and of course save this new state in the cache for the next cycle).