# Prevent listbox flicker from list background

Tags: winforms, listbox

I have a listbox with DrawMode = OwnerDraw.

I have noticed a flicker that is the result of the listbox background being drawn before my custom DrawItem is called. Thus even if I use a single e.Graphics.FillRectangle call it would still cause flicker.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent this flicker, perhaps preventing the listbox backgroundcolor from being drawn?

Comment: See [Double buffered ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1131912/719186).

Comment: That is one of the ones I've tried, the problem is that the flicker is in the color of the listbox background, which I'm not drawing at all. So my guess is that something else is filling the entire listbox with the background color before calling my draw code.