# Why the listbox control keep flickering when adding new items and when scrolling down/up even if using double buffering?

Tags: c#, winforms

is there another way to avoid the flickering?

The usercontrol code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LB
{
    public partial class CustomListBox : ListBox
    {
        public CustomListBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.SetStyle(
                          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                          ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                          ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
                          ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                          ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor
                          , true);
        }

        private void CustomListBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

the form1 where using it in the drawitem event

```
private void listBoxCroppedImages_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Index == -1) || (e.Index >= MyItems.Count))
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
    }
    else
    {
        var myItem = MyItems[e.Index];
        if (listBoxCroppedImages.SelectedItems.Contains(myItem))
        {
            using (var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(myItem.ItemColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);
            }

            using (var textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(myItem.Message, listBoxCroppedImages.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);
            }
            using (var textBrush = new SolidBrush(myItem.ItemColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(myItem.Message, listBoxCroppedImages.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if I remove the bottom part, it will not add items anymore but will repeat on the same item line in the listbox. but with the bottom part it keeps adding items but then also flickering a lot.

the second else part that draw the new items make it flicker.

```
using (var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window))
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);
}
using (var textBrush = new SolidBrush(myItem.ItemColor))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(myItem.Message, listBoxCroppedImages.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds);
}
```

tried the above even with double buffering it keeps flickering.

Comment: A bit old, but have you tried the solutions mentioned here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131912/double-buffered-listbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004868/14171304